How can I write a query for the API to return one item by ID instead of all items?
I have SharePoint 2019. I was trying to open an API to select 1 item by ID but I find it returns all items in the list whatever id= I provide.
https://sharepoint.example.com/_api/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?$select=*&id=12
Is it normal to do this behavior?

You have not added the correct syntax to get item id by id.
Please try this below REST API to get list item by id:
https://<site url>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<list-title>')/items(<item-id>)

Thanks @Dylan Cristy,
We can omit $select=* to get all fields in the result.

I think it's also worth noting that the $select=* is unnecessary. Omitting the $select operator will return all fields/columns by default: /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items(12) will return all fields/columns for item with ID 12.

Yes, you can omit $select=*.
